# Crafting regex for Fail2ban and NGINX

Tags: nginx, regex, fail2ban

I'm having some trouble understanding how to craft a regex to capture probe attempts on my nginx webserver.

I would like to craft a filter to catch sites hitting certain files (by name) and/or by php error.

My log file example is below:

```
2023/11/04 14:40:26 [error] 1341#1341: *46805 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 194.113.235.169, server: www.server.org, request: "GET /index2.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9999", host: "www.server.org", referrer: "https://www.server.org/index2.php"
```

I was playing around with a regex builder and came up with the below string:

```
\bPrimary|\bscript|\bunknown
```

Which would match the phrase.

How do I build this into a fail2ban filter?

Logwatch also sends me a nice summary of errors, which I'd like to be able to selectively start adding to filters.

```
Requests with error response codes
    400 Bad Request
       null: 60 Time(s)
       \xC0/\xC00\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA8\xCC\xA9\xC0\x ... x09\xC0\x14\xC0: 11 Time(s)
       *: 7 Time(s)
       /: 6 Time(s)
       google.com:443: 2 Time(s)
       $\x11\xA2\x8D*^\xB5\xBB\x1D: 1 Time(s)
       )Dxx\x1D'\xB7\x00\x00: 1 Time(s)
       ,c(\x0B\xF1: 1 Time(s)
       /.env: 1 Time(s)
       /api/v4/cloud/subscription/self-serve-status: 1 Time(s)
       /basic_status: 1 Time(s)
       /manager/html: 1 Time(s)
       /manager/text/list: 1 Time(s)
       /nginx_status: 1 Time(s)
       /nginx_stub: 1 Time(s)
       /private/api/v1/service/premaster: 1 Time(s)
       /status: 1 Time(s)
       /stub_status: 1 Time(s)
       4\xE8%\x98w4\x0Bcry\xAA%\x82r\x0B&\x8B\x9D: 1 Time(s)
       LM: 1 Time(s)
       \x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x ... x00\x00\x00\x00: 1 Time(s)
       \x11\x97e\xDC\x0CD\xBA\xDFS\x00\x00*\xC0+\ ... xA8\xCC\xAA\xC0: 1 Time(s)
       \xC0((+\x9B<8\xFA: 1 Time(s)
       `\x0B!\xCE,\xD5}L7/nh&\x08+\xAB\xCA: 1 Time(s)
       mstshash=Administr: 1 Time(s)
404 Not Found
       /wp-content/plugins/WordPressCore/include.php: 7 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/core-plugin/include.php: 4 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/include.php: 4 Time(s)
       /wp-content/themes/include.php: 4 Time(s)
       /wp-includes/images/include.php: 4 Time(s)
       /wp-includes/widgets/include.php: 4 Time(s)
       /%25: 3 Time(s)
       //wp-content/plugins/seoplugins/mar.php: 3 Time(s)
       //wp-content/themes/seotheme/db.php?u: 3 Time(s)
       //wp-content/themes/seotheme/mar.php: 3 Time(s)
       /?author=2: 3 Time(s)
       /admin/plugins/plupload/examples/upload.php: 3 Time(s)
       /api/v4/emoji/name/%F0%9F%98%86: 3 Time(s)
       /wp-content/themes/sketch/404.php: 3 Time(s)
       /wp-login.php: 3 Time(s)
       /.index.php: 2 Time(s)
       /99vt: 2 Time(s)
       /Res/login.html: 2 Time(s)
       /aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaqr: 2 Time(s)
       /actuator/gateway/routes: 2 Time(s)
       /backup/: 2 Time(s)
       /blog/: 2 Time(s)
       /new/: 2 Time(s)
       /old/: 2 Time(s)
       /owa/auth/x.js: 2 Time(s)
       /sitemap: 2 Time(s)
       /sitemap.txt: 2 Time(s)
       /sitemap.xml: 2 Time(s)
       /style.php?sig=update&domain=51.79.124.111: 2 Time(s)
       /temp/: 2 Time(s)
       /test/: 2 Time(s)
       /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php: 2 Time(s)
       /webui/: 2 Time(s)
       /wordpress/: 2 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/drag-and-drop-multiple ... -upload-cf7.css: 2 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/wp-meta-and-date-remov ... js/inspector.js: 2 Time(s)
       /wp-content/themes/seotheme/db.php?u: 2 Time(s)
       /wp/: 2 Time(s)
       /.git/config: 1 Time(s)
       /.well-known/: 1 Time(s)
       /.well-knownold/: 1 Time(s)
       //wp-content/plugins/WordPressCore/include.php: 1 Time(s)
       //wp-content/plugins/fix/up.php: 1 Time(s)
       /99vu: 1 Time(s)
       /?author=3: 1 Time(s)
       /?author=4: 1 Time(s)
       /ACio: 1 Time(s)
       /KjDKeIsQhh.php: 1 Time(s)
       /Login.jsp: 1 Time(s)
       /Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau: 1 Time(s)
       /ab2g: 1 Time(s)
       /ab2h: 1 Time(s)
       /actuator/health: 1 Time(s)
       /admin/: 1 Time(s)
       /admin/ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php: 1 Time(s)
       /admin/events/lib/external/responsive_file ... ager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /admin/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /admin/js/kcfinder/upload.php: 1 Time(s)
       /admin/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /ads.txt: 1 Time(s)
       /api/session/properties: 1 Time(s)
       /app/rest/users/id:1/tokens/RPC2: 1 Time(s)
       /assets/elfinder/elfinder.html: 1 Time(s)
       /assets/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /assets/js/kcfinder/upload.php: 1 Time(s)
       /assets/plugins/elfinder/elfinder.html: 1 Time(s)
       /assets/plugins/kcfinder/upload.php: 1 Time(s)
       /assets/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /assets/scripts/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /autodiscover/autodiscover.json?@zdi/Powershell: 1 Time(s)
       /autodiscover/autodiscover.json?a..foo.var ... ol=%50owershell: 1 Time(s)
       /backup: 1 Time(s)
       /basic_status: 1 Time(s)
       /bc: 1 Time(s)
       /bk: 1 Time(s)
       /cf_scripts/scripts/ajax/ckeditor/ckeditor.js: 1 Time(s)
       /cgi-bin/authLogin.cgi: 1 Time(s)
       /cgi-bin/config.exp: 1 Time(s)
       /cgi-bin/vitogate.cgi: 1 Time(s)
       /cm3Z: 1 Time(s)
       /cms/tinymce/filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /cms/vendor/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /config.json: 1 Time(s)
       /dview8/api/usersByLevel: 1 Time(s)
       /editor/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /favicon-32x32.png: 1 Time(s)
       /file-manager/: 1 Time(s)
       /file-manager/backend/makefile: 1 Time(s)
       /file-manager/backend/permissions: 1 Time(s)
       /file-manager/backend/text: 1 Time(s)
       /geoserver/web/: 1 Time(s)
       /graph_view.php?action=tree_content&node=1 ... %2810%29%3B--+-: 1 Time(s)
       /hejwjpam.php?Fox=d3wL7: 1 Time(s)
       /home: 1 Time(s)
       /humans.txt: 1 Time(s)
       /index.php: 1 Time(s)
       /index2.php: 1 Time(s)
       /info.php: 1 Time(s)
       /js/fileManager/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /js/kcfinder/upload.php: 1 Time(s)
       /js/tinymce4/plugins/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /lib/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /main: 1 Time(s)
       /media/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /new: 1 Time(s)
       /nginx_status: 1 Time(s)
       /nginx_stub: 1 Time(s)
       /old: 1 Time(s)
       /owa/: 1 Time(s)
       /owa/auth.owa: 1 Time(s)
       /plugins/content/apismtp/apismtp.php?test=hello: 1 Time(s)
       /plugins/kcfinder/upload.php: 1 Time(s)
       /plugins/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /po-admin/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /po-content/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /public/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /public/js/libraries/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /public/scripts/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /remote/login: 1 Time(s)
       /resources/plugins/tiny_mce/plugins/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /responsive_filemanager/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /server-status: 1 Time(s)
       /showLogin.cc: 1 Time(s)
       /solr/: 1 Time(s)
       /static/historypage.js: 1 Time(s)
       /sugar_version.json: 1 Time(s)
       /t4: 1 Time(s)
       /telescope/requests: 1 Time(s)
       /tinymce/filemanager/dialog.php: 1 Time(s)
       /tutor/filter?searched_word&searched_tutio ... ed_duration[]=0: 1 Time(s)
       /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xml: 1 Time(s)
       /version: 1 Time(s)
       /webfig/: 1 Time(s)
       /wordpress: 1 Time(s)
       /wp: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-admin/: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-admin/css/colors/blue/blue.php?wall=ZW ... EJvdCI7Pz4nKTs=: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config._1: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config._2: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config._backup: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.back: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php__: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php______: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php__olds: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_backup: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2003: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2004: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2005: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2007: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2009: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2010: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2011: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2016: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2018: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2019: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2020: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2022: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_old2023: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php_original: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.phpc: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.phpd: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.phpn: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.phpnew: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.phpold: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.phps: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php~1: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php~bk: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.prod: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.prod.php.txt: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.production: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.rej: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.sav: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.save: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.save.1: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.save.2: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.stage: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.sublime-project: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.swn: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.swo: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.tar: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.temp: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.templ: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.tmp: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.uk: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.un~: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.us: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.vb: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.vbproj: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.wp-config.php.swo: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config_good: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/apikey/apikey.php?test=hello: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/media-library-assistan ... ite/patrowl.svg: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/media-library-assistant/readme.txt: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/wordpresscore/include.php: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/wp-stats-manager/includes/: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/wp-stats-manager/languages/: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/plugins/wp-stats-manager/notifications.php: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/themes/themify-ultra/style.css: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/themes/twentytwentythree/index.php: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/upgrade/: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/upgrade/upfile.php: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-content/uploads/: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-includes/: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-includes/autoload_classmap.php: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-json/wp/v2/users/2: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-json/wp/v2/users/4: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-json/wp/v2/users/5: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-plain.php: 1 Time(s)
```

example log entry for error:

```
31.208.250.224 - - [04/Nov/2023:20:44:57 -0400] "GET /wp-config._backup HTTP/1.1" 404 5056 "https://www.server.blog//wp-config._backup" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
```

To summarize:

1. I'd like to get help making a filter catching "primary script unknown"
2. I'd like to get help making a filter catching the 404 errors probing the server, starting with wp-config, and to add/expand the list as it grows (e.g. .env files)
3. Is there a good reference on how to learn the regex black magic?  I've looked at various sites and I'm just not understanding all the magic.

I'd appreciate any help on this.  Thank you.

Debug link - https://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5CbPrimary%7C%5Cbscript%7C%5Cbunknown%7C+%5B%5B%5Dclient+%28%3F%3A%5C%5B%3F%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%3A%3Af%7B4%2C6%7D%3A%29%3F%28%3FP%3Cip4%3E%28%3F%3A%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%29%7B3%7D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%7C%28%3FP%3Cip6%3E%28%3F%3A%5B0-9a-fA-F%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%3A%3A%3F%7C%3A%3A%29%7B1%2C7%7D%28%3F%3A%5B0-9a-fA-F%5D%7B1%2C4%7D%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%3A%29%3A%29%29%29%5C%5D%3F%7C%28%3FP%3Cdns%3E%5B%5Cw%5C-.%5E_%5D%2A%5Cw%29%29%5B%5D%5D&str=2023%2F11%2F04+22%3A23%3A52+%5Berror%5D+1341%231341%3A+%2A58181+FastCGI+sent+in+stderr%3A+%22Primary+script+unknown%22+while+reading+response+header+from+upstream%2C+client%3A+94.156.69.32%2C+server%3A+www.wolfandraven.blog%2C+request%3A+%22GET+%2Fwp-content%2Fplugins%2Fcore-plugin%2Finclude.php+HTTP%2F1.1%22%2C+upstream%3A+%22fastcgi%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9999%22%2C+host%3A+%22www.wolfandraven.blog%22&flavor=python

Comment: What have you tried so far? The fail2ban manual has a pretty clear section about how to create custom filters so what part of it did you try to apply, what didn't go as expected and what was the specific error you encountered?

Comment: As mentioned, I used a regex builder and have the initial find string - `failregex = \bPrimary|\bscript|\bunknown| [[]client <HOST>[]]`.  I'm working on having it capture the host ip, which is different than other logs that work (client: x.x.x.x).  I'll add the debug link to the bottom of the main post.

Comment: Why are you using the error log rather than the access log+404?

Comment: Well, I guess that's where I noticed the errors/issues happening.  Then it became a quest to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
failregex = ^.*, client: <HOST>.*(Credit-private.php).*$
            ^.*, client: <HOST>.*(admin.php).*$
            ^.*, client: <HOST>.*(fm1.php).*$
            ^.*, client: <HOST>.*(M1.php).*$
            ^.*, client: <HOST>.*(style.php).*$
            ^.*, client: <HOST>.*(wp-blog.php).*$
```

The above pattern for regex will find the offending entries.  However, it doesn't seem to find it in one part of the log message, at least according to the regex tester.